# Last button not working in unity of my foreach loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a quiz where it spawn in the question and 4 Choices you have i have the color and other thing working but it will not change the color for the last choices when you click on it.It will not update

```
    public void Update()
    {
        //this is the current qusetion that you spawned in 
        if (CurrentQuestion == null)
            return;
       //this is to update the ScriptableObject so it will like the to work with no issues
        foreach (var item in ListOfCurrentButtons)
        {
            if (item.ChoiceHolder.StringforQuestion == null)
                return;
            var NewItem = CurrentQuestion.RngQU.Find((x) => x.StringforQuestion == item.ChoiceHolder.StringforQuestion);
            if (NewItem != null)
                NewItem.HasClickedOn = item.ChoiceHolder.HasClickedOn;
        }
    
        if (currentChoice == null)
            return;
        foreach (var item in CurrentQuestion.RngQU)
        {
            var NewItem = CurrentQuestion.RngQU.Find((x) => x.StringforQuestion == currentChoice.StringforQuestion);
            if (NewItem == null)
                return;
            NewItem.HasClickedOn = true;
          //this is where the problem is 
            item.HasClickedOn = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is with the  foreach loop and how it does thing first int find the current Choices you picked on the ui

```
var NewItem = CurrentQuestion.RngQU.Find((x) =\> x.StringforQuestion == currentChoice.StringforQuestion);
```

before this in when it loads the button it add a listener event that turns the HasClickedOn to true this is good but i need to chage it back to false when you click on a different button where this come in to play

```
        item.HasClickedOn = false;
```

it work with the other but not the last one I try turning it to a for loop and asking chatgpt to help

Comment: if you need all 3 codes that go in it i will put it on but  i think only the foreach need to be fix

Answer (score 0):

```
public void TaskOnClick(bool isRight, Choices choice)
{
    CurrentQuestion.TheAswer = isRight;
    currentChoice = choice;
    currentChoice.HasClickedOn = true;
} 
public void Update()
{
 if (CurrentQuestion == null || currentChoice == null)
   return;
 foreach (var item in CurrentQuestion.RngQU)
 {
  var NewItem = CurrentQuestion.RngQU.Find((x) => x.StringforQuestion == currentChoice.StringforQuestion);
  if (NewItem == null)
     return;
  NewItem.HasClickedOn = true;
  if (item.StringforQuestion != currentChoice.StringforQuestion)
  {
     item.HasClickedOn = false;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).